# laravel Unable to prepare route ... for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: laravel, serialization, routes

When I clear caches in my Laravel 5.2 project, I see this error message:

[LogicException]
  Unable to prepare route [panel] for serialization. Uses Closure.

I think that it's related with a route

```
Route::get('/article/{slug}', 'Front@slug');
```

associated with a particular method in my controller:

```
public function slug($slug) {
    $article = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();

    $id = $article ->id_article ;

    if ( ($article=== null) || (is_null($id)) ) return view('errors/Db');

    else return view('detail')->with(array('article'=> $article,  'title'=>'My title - '.$article->title)); 
}`
```

In short, from a master view I pass $slug, that is a shortlink to the article, with $slug , which is unique in the database, I identify the record and then I pass it's contents to the detail view.

I didn't have any problem when I wrote the method, infact it worked like a charm, but after I cleaned caches, I get that error and the links in the master view don't show any shortcode.

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45266254/edit) your question to include the rest of your routes (especially the panel route)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

> I think that it's related with a route
>
> ```
> Route::get('/article/{slug}', 'Front@slug');
> ```
>
> associated with a particular method in my controller:

No, thats not it. The error message is coming from the `route:cache` command, not sure why clearing the cache calls this automatically.

The problem is a route which uses a Closure instead of a controller, which looks something like this:

```
//                       Thats the Closure
//                             v 
Route::get('/some/route', function() {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Since Closures can not be serialized, you can not cache your routes when you have routes which use closures.

Comment: so the command => php artisan route:cache   not working on laravel? a bug?

Comment: @robspin I don't think it's a bug, since it's explicitly said in Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/deployment#optimization (check section Optimizing Route Loading)

Comment: Since this feature uses PHP serialization, you may only cache the routes for applications that exclusively use controller based routes. PHP is not able to serialize Closures.   So  not use the php artisan route:cache is the right way! Just use the php artisan cache:clear

Comment: so, any solution ?

Comment: see IBRAHIM EZZAT solution below. Essentially need to replace any closures with controller methods in your route files

Comment: Ya know....   I probably wouldn't have figure that one out.  This makes me curious if anyone has come up with library to serialize closures.

Answer (score 65):

If none of your routes contain closures, but you are still getting this error, please check

> routes/api.php

Laravel has a default auth api route in the above file.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

which can be commented or replaced with a call to controller method if required.

Comment: This is the right answer, when I comment it out the Route/api.php  Route functions, this error is gone. Thank you Manpreet.

Answer (score 52):

This is definitely a bug.Laravel offers predefined code in routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) { 
     return $request->user(); 
});
```

which is unabled to be processed by:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

This definitely should be fixed by Laravel team.(check the [link](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22034)),

simply if you want to fix it you should replace routes\api.php code with some thing like :

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'UserController@AuthRouteAPI');
```

and in UserController put this method:

```
 public function AuthRouteAPI(Request $request){
    return $request->user();
 }
```

Comment: Seems like a bug indeed. If they make it possible to use closures in routes then they should fix the artisan commands so that they at least don't give any errors.

Comment: Here's the relevant PR, which was closed :(  https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/4601

Answer (score 13):

The Actual solution of this problem is changing first line in web.php

Just replace Welcome route with following route

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
```

If still getting same error than you probab

Answer (score 7):

If you're coming to this problem because you've upgraded Laravel <5.8 project up to >=5.8, you've likely used the ./vendor/bin/carbon-upgrade method to upgrade the project as suggested by your terminal. In this case, you simply need to ***remove the following two blocks from the bottom of your composer.json*** file and composer install again:

```
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
```

Comment: this solved my problem

Comment: This is the right answer for this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

the solustion when we use routes like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

laravel call them Closure so you cant optimize routes uses as Closures you must route to controller to use `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score 6):

Check your **routes/web.php** and **routes/api.php**

Laravel comes with default route closure in routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

and routes/api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

if you remove that then try again to clear route cache.

Answer (score 5):

If someone is still looking for an answer, for me the problem was in routes/web.php file. Example:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

It is also Route, so yeah...Just remove it if not needed and you are good to go!
You should also follow answers provided from above.

Comment: Hi Aline Matos, no problem. It took me like whole day to figure it out what is wrong...Glad it helped.

Comment: what if it needed?

Comment: @Aziz just move it into a controller

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot this (at least in laravel 6):
The action property inside Route.php has all the info needed. A better error message should be possible to provide by laravel.

What I did was to add a dd($this->action) just before the exception is thrown here:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L917

With that in place I could easily pinpoint the location, in my case api.php and lines 22-24:

```php
array:6 [
  "middleware" => "api"
  "domain" => "local-api.mydomain.com"
  "uses" => Closure()^ {#6497
    class: "App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider"
    this: App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider {#5743 …}
    file: "./routes/api.php"
    line: "22 to 24"
  }
  "namespace" => "App\Http\Controllers"
  "prefix" => null
  "where" => []
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine.

1. Navigate to routes directory
2. Then open api.php
3. comment code that looks like this:
   `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) { return $request->user(); });`
4. Then run
   `php artisan optimize`

Answer (score -3):

check that your **web.php** file has this extension

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

my problem gone fixed by this way.