# Laravel route error 404(Not Found) on CentOs7

Tags: laravel

I created laravel project that work fine on my local windows pc. Once I upload to Centos7 server(via SSH), all my routes show 'Not Found 404, https://ibb.co/tHysggf ' except index page. Picture below is my project structure. I remove public folder and place index.php outside.

[image: laravel]

Appreciated much for all answer.

Comment: Did you change the permissions to allow apache/nginx to read and cache some of the code ?

Comment: Please post code from your routes, or where you configure it. Also don't post it as images.

Comment: Hi  EkinOf, I use apache not ngix. Could you pls advise of operation?. I' really newbie on Laravel and Linux.

Comment: Hi zuckerburg, Thanks just need to show that I modified structure.

Comment: Hi can you clear your cache and give permission to public folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 Open httpd.conf

```
   sudo vim /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

2 Make sure the DocumentRoot is pointing to the laravel project's public directory. Add the Directory element for that path and Allowoverride All... as follows

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/laravel/public/"

<Directory "/var/www/html/laravel/public">
Allowoverride All
</Directory>
```

3 Open .htaccess from ../laravel/public/ and make sure it has the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

4 Restart httpd services

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Comment: Hi I.Sh, I do not have public folder. Btw, could you pls help follow to this file structure , https://i.ibb.co/DpXqTwm/Clipboard03.jpg .

Comment: where is your public folder, you are remove and put index.php?

Answer (score 2):

May be this will help you.
You need to update your index.php file,

```
require __DIR__.'./vendor/autoload.php'; 
$app = require_once __DIR__.'./bootstrap/app.php';
```

And server.php

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'./index.php';
```

Comment: Hi Md.Sukel Ali, both index.php and server.php already set as yours. It work on local machine(Windows) but not work on Linux CentOs7.