# Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing my project on Laravel. When I optimize the project, I have a problem :

> **Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.**

I looked for any closures in web.php, but I didn't find anything

```
    <?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/','ReviewsController@main')->name('main');
Route::post('/','MailController@verify')->name('verifyPost');

Route::get('/reviews', 'ReviewsController@index')->name('reviews');
Route::post('/reviews','ReviewsController@add')->name('addReview');

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin','prefix' => 'admin'],function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin');
    Route::get('/reviews', 'Admin\ReviewsController@get')->name('admin.reviews');
    Route::get('/reviews/accepted/{id}','Admin\ReviewsController@accept')->where('id','\d+')->name('admin.accepted');
    Route::delete('/reviews/delete','Admin\ReviewsController@delete')->name('reviews.delete');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel Unable to prepare route ... for serialization. Uses Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure)

Answer (score 5):

in `api.php` file search and comment this **route** you will not get error..

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

and also in `web.php` file `route::group` is also **closure** and also comment them for test

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admin','prefix' => 'admin'],function () {
    Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin');
    Route::get('/reviews', 'Admin\ReviewsController@get')->name('admin.reviews');
    Route::get('/reviews/accepted/{id}','Admin\ReviewsController@accept')->where('id','\d+')->name('admin.accepted');
    Route::delete('/reviews/delete','Admin\ReviewsController@delete')->name('reviews.delete');
});
```

see what is [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Comment: No need to comment out Route group closure. It is routes group not a route closure

Answer (score 2):

Php routing cache command :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

if your application using controller based routes. It help for fast execution. But remember "Closure based routes cannot be cached"
So kindly convert your Closure routes to controller classes.

[For more information](https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#route-caching)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to Check "routes/api.php"