# Laravel - Error "Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure."

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and now i manage project that was left by someone.

i try to add a function to **API**, what i edit :

1) Add a Method :

`myproject/app/Http/Controllers/Api/ArticleController.php`

2) Add **Routes** to controler :

`myprojectmyproject/routes/api.php`

However, when i try to run `php artisan route:cache` i got below error :

> > **Route cache cleared! \n
> >     LogicException  : Unable to prepare route [/] for serialization. Uses Closure.**

my route file, **myproject/routes/api.php** :

```
Route::group (['prefix' => 'v1', 'middleware' => 'ValidateHeaderSignature'], function() {

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function() {
        Route::post('/login', 'Api\AuthController@login');
        Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
        Route::post('/login-social-media', 'Api\AuthController@loginSocialMedia');
        Route::post('/forgot-password', 'Api\AuthController@forgotPassword');        
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function() {
            Route::patch('/change-password', 'Api\AuthController@changePassword');
            Route::post('/logout', 'Api\AuthController@logout');
        });
    });


    Route::group(['prefix' => 'foundation-donate'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\FoundationDonateController@index');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'greeting-chat'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\GreetingChatController@index');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'prayer-time'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\PrayerTimeController@index');
        Route::get('/montly', 'Api\PrayerTimeController@getMontlyPrayerTimes');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'asmaul-husna'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\AsmaulHusnaController@index');
    });


    Route::group(['prefix' => 'guidance'], function () {
        Route::get('/zikir', 'Api\GuidanceController@zikirGuidances');
        Route::get('/prayer', 'Api\GuidanceController@prayerGuidances');
    });


    Route::group(['prefix' => 'duas'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\DuasController@index');
        Route::get('/index', 'Api\DuasController@index');
        Route::get('/all', 'Api\DuasController@allPrayers');
        Route::get('/category/{category}', 'Api\DuasController@category');
        Route::get('/show/{id}', 'Api\DuasController@show');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'zakat'], function () {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\ZakatController@index');
        Route::get('/index', 'Api\ZakatController@index');
        Route::get('/all', 'Api\ZakatController@allPrayers');
        Route::get('/category/{category}', 'Api\ZakatController@category');
        Route::get('/show/{id}', 'Api\ZakatController@show');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'playlist'], function () {
        Route::get('/zikir', 'Api\PlaylistSongController@playlistZikir');
        Route::get('/shalawat', 'Api\PlaylistSongController@playlistShalawat');
        Route::get('/duas', 'Api\PlaylistSongController@playlistDuas');
        Route::get('/murottal', 'Api\PlaylistSongController@playlistMurottal');
        Route::get('/songs', 'Api\PlaylistSongController@playlistSongs');
    });

    Route::group(['prefix' => 'dzikir'], function() {
        Route::get('/primary', 'Api\DzikirController@primaryDzikir');
        Route::get('/my-dzikir', 'Api\DzikirController@myDzikir');
        Route::get('/categories', 'Api\DzikirController@dzikirCategories');

        Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function() {
            Route::get('/point-total', 'Api\DzikirController@pointTotal');
            Route::get('/histories', 'Api\DzikirController@histories');
            Route::get('/total-dzikir-history', 'Api\DzikirController@totalDzikirHistory');
            Route::post('/post-dzikir', 'Api\DzikirController@postDzikir');
        });
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'sadaqah'], function() {
        Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function() {
            Route::get('/histories', 'Api\DzikirController@sadaqahHistories');
        });
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'article'], function() {
        Route::get('/', 'Api\ArticleController@index');
        Route::get('/daily-reflection', 'Api\ArticleController@getDailyReflection');
        Route::get('/get-random', 'Api\ArticleController@getRandom');
    });


    Route::group(['prefix' => 'notification'], function() {
        Route::get('/quote', 'Api\NotificationController@prayerQuotes');
    });


    Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function() {
        Route::get('/show', 'Api\UserController@show');
        Route::patch('/update-profile', 'Api\UserController@update');
    });
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'master'], function() {
        Route::get('/location', 'Api\MasterController@location');
    });

});
```

if i got error because of [**Uses Closure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure), why previous developer can populate route?

by run `php artisan route:list` i can see list of route that have ever made before.

any idea ?

===Update, Add routes/web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('register/activation/{code}', 'Auth\\RegisterController@activation')->name('register.activation');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    Route::get('/user-apps/list-index', ['as' => 'user-apps.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\UserAppsController@listIndex']);
    Route::get('/user-apps/resend-confirmation', ['as' => 'user-apps.resend-confirmation', 'uses' => 'Admin\\UserAppsController@resendConfirmation']);
    Route::resource('/user-apps', 'Admin\\UserAppsController');
    Route::get('/user/list-index', ['as' => 'user.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\UserController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/user', 'Admin\\UserController');
    Route::get('/dzikir-playlist-category/list-index', ['as' => 'dzikir-playlist-category.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistCategoryController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/dzikir-playlist-category', 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistCategoryController');

    Route::get('/dzikir-playlist/list-index', ['as' => 'dzikir-playlist.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/dzikir-playlist', 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistController');

    Route::get('/dzikir-playlist-homepage/list-index', ['as' => 'dzikir-playlist-homepage.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistHomepageController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/dzikir-playlist-homepage', 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistHomepageController');
    Route::get('/dzikir-playlist-my-zikir/list-index', ['as' => 'dzikir-playlist-my-zikir.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistMyZikirController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/dzikir-playlist-my-zikir', 'Admin\\DzikirPlaylistMyZikirController');
    Route::get('/greeting-chat/list-index', ['as' => 'greeting-chat.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\GreetingChatController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/greeting-chat', 'Admin\\GreetingChatController');
    Route::get('/foundation-donate/list-index', ['as' => 'foundation-donate.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\FoundationDonateController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/foundation-donate', 'Admin\\FoundationDonateController');
    Route::get('/asmaul-husna/list-index', ['as' => 'asmaul-husna.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\AsmaulHusnaController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/asmaul-husna', 'Admin\\AsmaulHusnaController');
    Route::get('/guidance/list-index', ['as' => 'guidance.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\GuidanceController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/guidance', 'Admin\\GuidanceController');
    Route::get('/content-category/list-index', ['as' => 'content-category.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\ContentCategoryController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/content-category', 'Admin\\ContentCategoryController');
    Route::get('/duas/list-index', ['as' => 'duas.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\DuasController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/duas', 'Admin\\DuasController');
    Route::get('/zakat/list-index', ['as' => 'zakat.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\ZakatController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/zakat', 'Admin\\ZakatController');
    Route::get('/quote/list-index', ['as' => 'quote.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\QuoteController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/quote', 'Admin\\QuoteController');
    Route::get('/playlist-song-category/list-index', ['as' => 'playlist-song-category.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\PlaylistSongCategoryController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/playlist-song-category', 'Admin\\PlaylistSongCategoryController');
    Route::get('/playlist-song/list-index', ['as' => 'playlist-song.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\PlaylistSongController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/playlist-song', 'Admin\\PlaylistSongController');
    Route::get('/album/list-index', ['as' => 'album.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\AlbumController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/album', 'Admin\\AlbumController');
    Route::get('/artist/list-index', ['as' => 'artist.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\ArtistController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/artist', 'Admin\\ArtistController');
    Route::get('/article/list-index', ['as' => 'article.list-index', 'uses' => 'Admin\\ArticleController@listIndex']);
    Route::resource('/article', 'Admin\\ArticleController');
});
```

Comment: What's the content of the `routes/web.php` file? Maybe the closure route is there (the default one for laravel's fresh install). You get this error as closures cannot be serialized and when you do `php artisan route:cache` under the hood it selializes the routes files and combine them in a single one as he lookup would be quicker.

Comment: @mdexp i have add code in question

Comment: If you don't need the `/` route simply comment it out or remove it. Then the caching should work as expected. If you need it, move that route to a controller as you did with all the other routes

Comment: *Closure based routes cannot be cached. To use route caching, you must convert any Closure routes to controller classes.* From [route caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#route-caching)

Comment: @mdexp what is it used for ?

Comment: It is used to display the default Laravel page that is shown when you load the root of the website in a browser. You can look at it by yourself by opening up the browser and pointing it at your project's public folder

Comment: check this solution  :::   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure/64590185#64590185

Answer (score 9):

When you want to use **route caching**, you **can't use closure** to register routes in any file.

As you still have the default route from the fresh Laravel installation in your `routes/web.php` file, you get this error because when you `do php artisan route:cache`, Laravel under the hood selializes the routes files and combine them in a single one as the lookup would be quicker.

To solve the issue, you can simply **remove the route** if that is unneeded or **move it to a controller** like you did for all the others routes.
The error should be gone then.

Answer (score 2):

Simply delete any route with a callback function like the default routes.

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

edit in

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'SomeController@someMethod');
```