# I am facing issue when login , getting the error on home route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

> Project is running fine but today when i start project get error   The
>   requested resource /home was not found on this server.  If i change
>   the home function and home route name then it works fine . when i run
>   php artisan optimize getting this error

```
 throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Unable to prepare route ... for serialization. Uses Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure)

Comment: thanks  not solve the issue if i want to use home  after login then it will give error  resource not found, if  i will change the function name and route then works