# Laravel 7: Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure. (LogicException)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have installed laravel 7 in my local server. When I run `php artisan route:cache` command then laravel return error:

> **LogicException**
>
> Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

I tried by running artisan commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dumpautoload
```

Here is content `routes/api.php`:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Comment: move call back to in contoroller then it will fixed `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'AnyController@index');

Comment: Why if closure routes return error, laravel developers passed closure route to `api.php` file then? @KamleshPaul

Comment: This problem was not in previous versions of the framework.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure) help? Closures can't be serialised, so you can't cache your routes if they are using Closures.

Answer (score 7):

You can't cache your routes if they are using Closure.

```
//                                      This is a Closure
//                                             v
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

Official docs (This is not new to Laravel 7) https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/deployment#optimization.

**To make `route:cache` work**, you may want to replace all requests using Closures to use a Controller method instead.

The route above, would then be like:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 'UserController@show');
```

And the controller method `UserController@show` would be like:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    return $request->user();
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: indeed that was the issue for me, api.php and web.php had closures like you said that caused this