# Laravel Unable to prepare route [{fallbackPlaceholder}] for serialization. Uses Closure

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-artisan, laravel-cache

when i run

```
php artisan route:cache
```

or

```
php artisan optimize
```

it's return :

Unable to prepare route [{fallbackPlaceholder}] for serialization. Uses Closure.

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:1150

> ```
> 1146|      */
> 1147|     public function prepareForSerialization()
> 1148|     {
> 1149|         if ($this->action['uses'] instanceof Closure) {
> 1150|             throw new LogicException("Unable to prepare route [{$this->uri}] for serialization. Uses Closure.");
> 1151|         }
> 1152|
> 1153|         $this->compileRoute();
> 1154|
>
>   +14 vendor frames   15  artisan:37
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
> ```

What should I do now to solve this problem?????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel Unable to prepare route ... for serialization. Uses Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266254/laravel-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure)

Comment: i saw and try this.  but not woking for me.

Comment: Did you move all of your closure functions to controller classes?

Comment: yes. i move all  closure functions to controller.

Comment: i solve my problem with install by fresh Laravel.