# How to fix Closure ? not work in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Unable to prepare route `[api/user]` for serialization. Uses Closure. at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:1150`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45266254/9636400.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cache routes if you are using a closure. The closure is this part
`public function (Request $request) { return $request->user(); }`

Instead, if you move the code into a controller you'll be able to cache the routes and eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0):

pls run php artisan route:list and check if there is any Closure in that list.